# ASP.NET Charting - Minimum length for StackedBar

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have built a chart with stacked bars from a custom DataTable that has values from 0 to about 150000, resulting in some bars being very long, and some bars being very short, as you can see in the image below.

[image: chart]

The value of each bar is in the description inside parentheses. As you can see, for small values like 10, 20, 120, the bar is not even visible. Is there a way to set a "minimum length" for a stackedbar so it's at least visible even if the value is small?

I've tried to set a smaller interval, like 10000 or 20000 but it's not visible as well.